# Detecting silence from float audio values

Tags: audio

I'm reading the audio data of a file as float, and I get for example these value:

```
-4,151046E+34 
-2,365558E+38 
6,068741E+26 
-4,141856E+34 
-2,179363E+38 
 1,177772E-04 
-1,035052E+34 
-1,#QNAN 
 2,668123E-20 
-1,0609E+37 
-2,153349E+38 
 1,105884E-16 
-4,25223E+37 
-1,#QNAN 
-3,718855E+22 
-1,695596E+38
```

I would like to detect when silence starts and ends.

Do these values represent values that are directly related to volume or would a value of 0 represent the value at this point in this screenshot, and I need to look at rather many of these values to detect silence?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silence is a notion tied to perception which has an attribute of time ... silence cannot happen for just an instant of time surrounded by loud audio since it will not be perceived as silence

Silence happens when the audio curve is at or does not vary much from the zero crossing point for some perceivable period of time ... you cannot have listenable audio followed by silence which lasts for just an instant of time followed by listenable audio ... that is not silence ... your eardrum or the membrane of a microphone in a silent room does not vibrate ... as the loudness of a room increases from silence those surfaces begin to wobble ... the plot you show can be thought of as visualizing this wobble ... on the plot the only silence happens during that flat line period of time at the beginning

To programmatically identify when silence occurs you need two parameters

- some maximum height of audio curve below which you declare silence happens
- some minimum length of time the audio curve stays below that max height

You can experiment with guessing these values ... now lets identify when silence happens

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    //  somehow your audio_buffer gets populated

    flag_in_candidate_silence := false          //  current sample is quiet
    flag_currently_in_declared_silence := false //  current stretch of samples are in silence period

    total_num_samples := len(audio_buffer) // identify how many samples

    max_vol := 0.1        //  max volume and still a silence candidate
    min_num_samples := 2000 //  minimum number of samples necessary to declare silence has happened
                            //  value used is dependent on sampling rate

    curr_num_samples_found := 0

    index_silence_starts := 0
    index_silence_ends := 0

    for curr_sample := 0; curr_sample < total_num_samples; curr_sample++ {

        curr_amplitude := audio_buffer[curr_sample]

        if curr_amplitude < max_vol { // current sample is candidate for silence

            index_silence_ends = curr_sample

            if flag_in_candidate_silence != true { // previous sample was not a candidate

                index_silence_starts = curr_sample
            }

            if curr_num_samples_found > min_num_samples {

                //  we are inside a period of silence !!!!!!!!!!!

                flag_currently_in_declared_silence = true
            }

            flag_in_candidate_silence = true
            curr_num_samples_found++ //  increment counter of current stretch of silence candidates

        } else {

            if flag_currently_in_declared_silence == true {

                fmt.Println("found silence stretch of samples from ", index_silence_starts, " to ", index_silence_ends)
            }

            flag_in_candidate_silence = false
            flag_currently_in_declared_silence = false
            curr_num_samples_found = 0
        }
    }

    if flag_currently_in_declared_silence == true {

        fmt.Println("found silence stretch of samples from ", index_silence_starts, " to ", index_silence_ends)
    }
}
```

(code not tested - spouted directly from forehead)